# The NSManagedObject model generated on XCode 7 not working in XCode 6

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode6, xcode7

The NSManagedObject model generated on XCode 7 are not working in XCode 6. But when I try switch to xcode 6 and create the model, the xcode 6 crash immediately. The bug is here: https://openradar.appspot.com/22602278

So I have to create the model in xcode 7. But when I switch to xcode 6, the build will not success.

Comment: Just curious why you're switching back to 6? Also, I noticed that the newer NSManagedObjects use Optionals in Swift, while the older ones did not. For example, my old files would say `@NSManaged var item : String`, and the new ones add a `?` at the end. Don't know if that's causing the crash...

Comment: @Tim Because some of my sdks I am using not work very well under xcode 7 and ios 9. That's why I write the code in 7 and deploy the app in 6

Comment: Did you check the Optionals, see if that's the difference? I don't know how that looks in Obj-C, but it's pretty obvious in the Swift files.

Comment: @Tim No. It's the NSSet <Editor> *editors problem.

Comment: @yongho it's just the use of lightweight generics? Can you just delete the `<Editor>` part? It doesn't affect anything at runtime, it's just an annotation for the compiler, and Core Data is about providing the compiler with an idea of what'll happen at runtime.

Comment: That Openradar issue doesn't describe the same problem that you describe here.